# Parsing data and removing invisible characters like carriage return

Tags: java, parsing, split

I am stuck and for the life of me I can't figure out why I am not getting this data to parse out into 5 tokens.

I load the data below in a file called `test.dat`:

> Row1: 1236~~Tier 5~~54~~updated~~01/05/2019
>
> Row2: 1255934~~Tier 1~~30~~Meeting series continued to review period.~~8/21/2018
>
> Row3: 12556~~Tier 1~~30~~Team began to map out Customer Harm Scenarios in this ~~8/21/2018
>
> Row4: 1255936~~Tier 1~~30~~week's calls.
>
> As of now, calls set through August 8th (`~~8/21/2018`) end of test file.

See how **Row 4** in this editor shows the return carriage? In my file it does not have a visible line break like it does here. It must be hidden characters.

This seems to be causing the problem. I tried to remove it, but nothing seems to work.

**Here is my code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class MergeData {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter master_file:");
    String master = loadFile();
    HashMap masterMap = readData(master);
}

public static String loadFile(){

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String fileName = new String();
    try{
        fileName = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("opening file... "+ fileName+"\n");

    }catch(IOException nfe){
        System.err.println("Invalid Format!");
    }   

    return fileName;
}

public static HashMap readData(String file){

   HashMap dataMap = new HashMap();
   try {
       FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
       String line;

       int rowCnt = 0;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String clean = line.replaceAll("(?:\\n|\\r)", "");
            String[] fields = clean.split("~~");
            int size = fields.length;
            System.out.println("delimiter size:"  + size );
            rowCnt = rowCnt +1;

            String f1 = null;
            String f2 = null;
            String f3 = null;
            String f4 = null;
            String f5 = null;

            if(size == 5){
                f1 = fields[0]; 
                f2 = fields[1]; 
                f3 = fields[2];
                f4 = fields[3];
                f5 = fields[4]; 
            } else {
                System.out.println("!!! INVALID ROW: id---->" + fields[0]);
            }

            System.out.println(
              "rowCnt:" +rowCnt+ " f1:" +f1+ "----f2:" +f2+ 
              "----f3:" +f3+ "----f4:" + f4+ "----f5:" + f5 +"\n\n");
        }

        br.close();
        fileReader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("\n File Read Error \n" +e );
    }

    return dataMap;
}
}
```

Comment: Try replaceAll("[^\w~]",""); to remove other characters and not only \\r and \\n

Comment: this gives an error: C:\>javac MergeData.java
MergeData.java:69: error: illegal escape character
                String clean = line.replaceAll("[^\w~]","");

Comment: I tried this: String clean = line.replaceAll("[^\\w~]","");

Comment: And it did not solve the problem... what was that supposed to do?

Comment: It is supposed to remove all characters different from alphanumeric (\w) and tilda ~

Comment: When you ran the code from the example above on the data I defined with the code you have, did it work and parse all 4 rows into five string in the array of items?